# Record padding in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Sorry about the title, I couldn't come up with anything better.

I have a table to log when a person travels to another country.

The table contains his trips, with a date and the destination country.

```
date       dest
2017-07-10 GER
2017-07-15 ITA
2017-07-17 GER
```

How would I get a list of where he is every day of the year from the data above, to obtain something like this:

```
date       in
2017-07-10 GER
2017-07-11 GER
2017-07-12 GER
2017-07-13 GER
2017-07-14 GER
2017-07-15 ITA
2017-07-16 ITA
2017-07-17 GER
```

It this possible via a `SELECT`?

Comment: no, but you don't really need to. If you want to present it like that in your application, your application code can do that work to insert dummy rows much more easily. Or use some sort of calendar view maybe with the stays as "events" between each time interval. I don't know, depends what your actual goal is

Comment: Yes, I can do it on the front-end, was just wondering if MySQL could do it.

Comment: not very easily no, it's hard to magic rows that don't exist, kind of goes against the principles of Set theory on which SQL is founded. It would not be a nice query, might even require some looping in a stored procedure or something. In general in SQL it's hard to do anything that compares different rows from the same resultset (as you'd have to do here to get the intervals in order to insert the dummies), it's just not how SQL is designed to operate.